# Uncaught TypeError: fs.access is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, browserify

I want to make an html page which will convert csv file to json objects.

I am using csvtojson npm module to achieve this.

I am using "require" and browserify. But when I run the command

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Where main.js is my actual code. I get fs.exists is not defined. I checked on stackoverflow and found out that it is deprecated. So, I used fs.access instead. I simply changed the bundle.js file and changed fs.exists to fs.access. But now I am getting error that fs.access is not a function.

Here is my main.js file

```
console.log("hi2");
$("#upload").on("click", function () {
    console.log("fff");
    const csvFilePath=document.getElementById('fileUpload').files[0];
    console.log("hi");
    const csv = require('csvtojson');
    csv()
    .fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .on('json',(jsonObj)=>{
        console.log(jsonObj)
    })
    .on('done',(error)=>{
        console.log('end')
    })
});
```

html file -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code snippet for bundle.js where I made the change-

```
  Converter.prototype.fromFile = function (filePath, cb, options) {
  var fs = require('fs');
  var rs = null;
  if (typeof cb ==="object" && typeof options === "undefined"){
    options=cb;
    cb=null;
  }
  this.wrapCallback(cb, function () {
    if (rs && rs.destroy) {
      rs.destroy();
    }
  });
  fs.access(filePath, function (exist) {
    if (exist) {
      rs = fs.createReadStream(filePath,options);
      rs.pipe(this);
    } else {
      this.emit('error', new Error("File not exists"));
    }
  });
  return this;
};
```

Comment: `changed fs.exists to fs.access` - where? it's not in anyting you posted

Comment: I've added the code snippet of bundle.js

Comment: what version of nodejs

Comment: Node version - 6.11.4

Comment: you haven't "installed" `fs` using npm I hope

Comment: So we have to install this separately ?

Comment: Installed fs from npm but still the same error. If this was the problem it would have given error at require("fs"); line I guess.

Comment: Are you trying to run bundle.js in a browser?  Because there is no `fs` module available in a browser.  That code runs in node.js, not in a browser.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I am running it in browser. Do I need to start a server on my local machine to do this ? If yes, can you please explain how can I do this ?

Comment: Well, you need to either find code you can use that is entirely client-side code (but you won't have access to the local file system from pure client code) or you will need to run a server, upload the file to the server and then convert it on the server where you can run any node.js code.  How are you loading this web page now?  Does it come from an http server?  Or are you just loading it from the local file system into the browser.

Comment: I just want to load the file on the browser and do the conversion and show json object in console using console.log